# PHP output html table losing tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my Wordpress site (Twenty Thirteen theme), I tried to get content from outside and output the data to HTML table (so I can use the jQuery tablesorter for arrangement). However, I found that I would lose the HTML tag in Wordpress?!

Here is my testing code in php :

```
<?php
$result = '<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr class="even"> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr class="odd"> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr class="even"> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr class="odd"> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> ';
echo $result;
?>
```

This code is fine in other place. In Wordpress, what I got is

```
Last Name
First Name
Email
Due
Web Site




Smith
John
jsmith@gmail.com
$50.00
http://www.jsmith.com


Bach
Frank
fbach@yahoo.com
$50.00
http://www.frank.com


Doe
Jason
jdoe@hotmail.com
$100.00
http://www.jdoe.com


Conway
Tim
tconway@earthlink.net
$50.00
http://www.timconway.com
```

It seems like I lost all the tags. I tried to use htmlentities but the result is the same. Can someone tell me how to generate table correctly? Thanks!!

Comment: are you adding this code directly into a page/post?

Comment: yes, I use these plugins: Allow PHP in Posts and Pages, Always Edit in HTML for editing HTML and php code.

Comment: it would seem there is an issue with one/both of the plugins, you should really just use ftp and create template/child themes etc. if your doing more than a trivial amount of custom php in wordpress

Comment: After testing, I think it's the Allow PHP in Posts and Pages that causes the problem. I changed to use Insert PHP as a solution. I will try to use child theme for later use. Thanks!